# datePicker.getMonth() +1 doesn't give expected result

Tags: android, android-datepicker

```
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Date selected:" + datePicker.getMonth()+1+
            "/"+ datePicker.getDayOfMonth() +
            "/"+ datePicker.getYear() +"\n" +
            "Time Slected:" + timePicker.getCurrentHour() + 
            ":"+ timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

BY adding 1 to the datePicker.getMonth(),i am getting month number

```
            output like->
            jan-01,feb-11,mar-21
```

But when i removing the "1" i am getting month number output like

```
            jan-0,feb-01,mar-02
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want parentheses.

```
(datePicker.getMonth()+1)
```

Otherwise you are doing string concatenation.

For example

If `getMonth()` returns 0 (for January), then

```
"Date selected: " + datePicker.getMonth()+1
```

is

```
("Date selected: " + 0) + 1
= "Date selected: 0" + 1
= "Date selected: 01"
```

But with parens

```
"Date selected: " + (datePicker.getMonth()+1)
= "Date selected: " + (0+1)
= "Date selected: " + 1
= "Date selected: 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The months are indexed starting from 0. So the first month gets number 0, second gets 1.

Comment: Correct, but not the problem in this question. (Se the answer by Ray Toal)

Comment: Well, the question was about 'getting the wrong month number', not about 'a random 1 appears'. You'd probably be right that answer is more helpful, but the question isn't really that understandable... (even after reformat)

Comment: I thought it was a month numbering issue at first, too, based on the question _title_, but the OP already had the `+ 1` in the code so I went with the string concat answer.  Hard to say, sometimes. :)